# Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference for multiple Select

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
function runDataComparision() {
    var iLen = document.frm3.dataComparision.options.length;
    var dataOptions = document.getElementById("dataComparision").options;
    // var dataOptions = document.getElementById("dataComparision").value;  Tried this
    // var dataOptions = document.frm3.dataComparision.options;  Tried this

    var result = [];
    var opt;
    for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        opt = dataOptions[i];
        if (opt.selected) {
            result.push(opt.value || opt.test);
        }
    }
    document.write(result);
}
```

I have a multi-select and I am trying to get all the selected options values using the above function. I have to run my app in IE11 in compatibility mode. I am not able to capture the selected options. What am I doing wrong? The above code works fine in Chrome.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have typos? Are you sure it should be "dataComparision" instead of "dataComparison"? (note the spelling mistake). "optioins" or "options"?

Comment: I have tried to change the "optioins" to "options" in the quesiton subject, but I could not. Message is: Question already exists.

Comment: Java is not Javascript.

Comment: It's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/uuoq8o47/